# find -exec rm for multiple files

Tags: find

I want to search for multiple files using `find` and delete all of them using `-exec` . I tried

```
find ./ -type f -name fileA -o -name fileB -exec rm {} \;
```

but this seems to remove files "fileB" only not fileAs.

Comment: It will also remove any directories called "fileB", incidentally.

Comment: @Wildcard Not with straight `rm` (it'll try but fail).

Comment: @Kusalananda, ah, right.

Answer (score 7):

`-o` also applies to the action, therefore you need to group things:

```
find ./ -type f \( -name fileA -o -name fileB \) -exec rm {} \;
```

BTW, your `find` implementation might also support `-delete`:

```
find ./ -type f \( -name fileA -o -name fileB \) -delete
```

Comment: and if it doesn't, it probably supports `-exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
 WARNING: it is possible that due to funny characters in directory names it is possible that unintended files might be deleted.

 find ./ -type f \( -name fileA -o -name fileB \) -print | xargs rm -f
```

Or if possible to catch those files with funny characters:

```
 NOTE: On some systems -print0 and -0 options are not available.  But this would be the preferred and safer method)

 find ./ -type f \( -name fileA -o -name fileB \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: I like how you came back nearly a year later just to add the note about file names, that's dedication. :D